# Multiple reusable modules in maven

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have a couple of java modules set up in IDEA and I am wanting to mavenize them. These java modules use classes from one another.

I was not quite sure how I should take up this and I decide to add modules on a maven project using IDEA. Hence first I created a maven project, let's name it pm1 which has a class let's name it TempClass1. Now this class can be used in other maven project. Hence I added another maven module - pm11 and tried to use TempClass1 with in pm11. It worked and I notices that IDEA had added module dependency of pm1 in pm11. So whole structure looks as -

[image: Maven Project]

But now when I do `mvn test` from pm11 then it fails with error message `package package1 does not exist` and it looks to me that it is because package1 is in a different maven project. And I am not sure how I could use classes which reside in a different maven project. I hope I am clear in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use classes of other maven projects, as long as there's a proper maven dependency defined in `pom.xml`. Ensure that the dependency is defined and its' scope is either undefined or relevant (You may have problems if the scope is `provided` for example).

Comment: I was using module creation from with IDEA while I should have been creating multi module maven project with dependency definition as you mentioned.